# Rendering inconsistencies in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

I have some weird problem in rendering some xhtml in IE 8 http://img709.imageshack.us/i/scrj.png/.
Here is the screenshot. As shown the greet me submit button is higher than the text field. Which is kind of odd. I checked with some other browsers and it works fine, it also works fine on Windows 7 with IE 8.

Here is the code for the site:
http://pastebin.com/cUkVA1HP

http://pastebin.com/nU4cdpDE
and the reset I'm using
http://pastebin.com/uyEbAsEF

I'm really puzzled by this strange behaviour. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If x = height of the text field, set the submit button's HEIGHT and LINE-HEIGHT to x.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Maybe I'm not doing it right? http://pastebin.com/vZFBTzyP